# use of undeclare identifier 'FBRequestConnection'

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Facebook functionality but I have an error in the following line of code:

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",[fbidarray objectAtIndex:j]] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error1)
```

The error is :

```
use of undeclare identifier 'FBRequestConnection'
```

I have imported the following frameworks:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Any of you knows why of the error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Use `FBSDKGraphRequest` instead.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                                 parameters:nil];
  [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // TODO: handle results or error of request.
  }];
```

This is from the docs

> Requests - FBSDKGraphRequest and FBSDKGraphRequestConnection are in FBSDKCoreKit and provide helpers to access the Graph API. They are very similar to FBRequest and FBRequestConnection in v3.x. By default they use [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] for issuing requests so you typically issue requests after login.

Also I searched the `FBRequestConnection` in the facebook sdk but couldn't find it.

Comment: You also need to add HTTPMethod:@"POST" parameter in order this call to be equal to the one in the question.